# How to send a request to MongoDB to update an object that contains an array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, api, mongoose

I am trying to update an object that contains an array in Mongo DB. This object looks like:

```
{id: 'idString',
propA: propA,
arrayB: [{propC: propC}, {propC: propD}, {propC: propE}]
```

I would like to send a request to update it into:

```
{id: 'idString',
propA: propA,
arrayB: [{propC: propABC}, {propC: propD}, {propC: propE}]
```

I am able to get it to work by doing this:

```
Object
.findByIdAndUpdate(req.params.id, {$set: req.body}})
```

white the request body being:

```
{id: 'idString',
propA: propA,
arrayB: [{propC: propABC}, {propC: propD}, {propC: propE}]
```

But is there a way I can send a request while the request body is just:

```
{id: 'idString',
arrayB: [{propC: propABC}]
```

that I don't have to include the entire array if I am only updating one item in this array? Right now if I do findByIdAndUpdate and send above as request body it would delete the rest of the array if they are not mentioned in the request body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on MongoDB's site. You still use $set but with the index number of the element in the array in your request body.

[$set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHwB0.png)

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/set/